# 'VA_ARGS', an invalid preprocessing token in macros Obj-C

Tags: objective-c

I use following technique to manage my logs. I print logs to `asl_log` and before, regards to flag `[DebugManager shared] isDebugging` I want to send log line to other class (method `addLogEvent`)

```
#if !defined(TheLog)
#define TheLog(fmt, ...) { \
if ([[DebugManager shared] isDebugging]) \
     addLogEvent(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,fmt,##__VA_ARGS__); \
}
#endif

#define __AF_MAKE_LOG_FUNCTION(LEVEL, NAME) \
inline void NAME(NSString *format, ...)\
{ \
 TheLog(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,format,##__VA_ARGS__);\ 
va_list arg_list; \
va_start(arg_list, format); \
NSString *formattedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:arg_list]; \
asl_add_log_file(NULL, STDERR_FILENO); \
asl_log(NULL, NULL, (LEVEL), "PREFIX:  %s", [formattedString UTF8String]); \
va_end(arg_list); \
}


// Something has failed.
__AF_MAKE_LOG_FUNCTION(ASL_LEVEL_ERR, AFLogError)

// Something is amiss and might fail if not corrected.
__AF_MAKE_LOG_FUNCTION(ASL_LEVEL_WARNING, AFLogWarning)

// The lowest priority for user log
__AF_MAKE_LOG_FUNCTION(ASL_LEVEL_INFO, AFLogDebug)
```

I map log level with `__AF_MAKE_LOG_FUNCTION(LEVEL, NAME)` and I need to call `TheLog(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,format,##__VA_ARGS__);\` from `inline void NAME(NSString *format, ...)`

I get an error:

> ```
> Pasting formed ',__VA_ARGS__', an invalid preprocessing token
> ```

How can I fetch `,__VA_ARGS__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
 TheLog(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,format,##__VA_ARGS__);\
```

is part of the definition of this macro:

```
#define __AF_MAKE_LOG_FUNCTION(LEVEL, NAME) \
```

Note that that macro does not take a variable argument list. Therefore, there's no `__VA_ARGS__` defined within its definition.

The fact that the function being defined by an instantiation of `__AF_MAKE_LOG_FUNCTION` — the `inline void NAME()` — takes a variable argument list isn't relevant. If that function wants to pass the variable argument list along to another function, it needs to do it using the stdarg functionality, as it does for `-[NSString initWithFormat:arguments:]`, but that doesn't work for your `TheLog` macro, because it's not designed to accept a `va_list`.

You can't do what you're attempting. Your `TheLog` macro is incompatible with how you're trying to use it. You would need to design an alternative version, such as:

```
#define TheLogv(fmt, args) { \
if ([[DebugManager shared] isDebugging]) \
     addLogEventv(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,fmt,args); \
}
```

Note that this would, in turn, require the existence of a function `addLogEventv()` which accepts a `va_list` instead of an actual variable argument list. Within the body of the function being defined by `__AF_MAKE_LOG_FUNCTION`, you'd have to start and end the list twice, once around each time you pass it to another function, because each function will "consume" it:

```
#define __AF_MAKE_LOG_FUNCTION(LEVEL, NAME) \
inline void NAME(NSString *format, ...)\
{ \
va_list arg_list; \
va_start(arg_list, format); \
 TheLogv(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,format,arg_list);\ 
va_end(arg_list); \
va_start(arg_list, format); \
NSString *formattedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:arg_list]; \
asl_add_log_file(NULL, STDERR_FILENO); \
asl_log(NULL, NULL, (LEVEL), "PREFIX:  %s", [formattedString UTF8String]); \
va_end(arg_list); \
}
```

You could also change your `TheLog()` macro to take an `NSString*` and simply pass in the `formattedString` that's already being created.

Comment: About call `TheLogv(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,format,arg_list);\ ` you pass  `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` and you use it inside `TheLogv(fmt, args)` that receives only 2 argumnets

Comment: Also calling `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` from  `inline void NAME` doesnt make sense because it will take wrong method String

Comment: Yes, you're correct that neither your `TheLog()` macro nor my modification of it accepts the function name as the first argument. And `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` will always be the name of the logging function created by `__AF_MAKE_LOG_FUNCTION()` (e.g. `AFLogError`), not the function which calls it. Those were problems in your original question that I didn't address. I addressed the specific compiler error you cited. If you want the name of the function calling `AFLogError()`, you'll need to wrap things in an additional layer of macros.

Comment: Thank you for efforts, ill except this answer for clarification